# Issue with lein ring uberjar and profiles

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

I am having troubles to make `lein ring uberjar` work with multiple profiles.

The following works:

```
lein new luminus profile-issue
cd profile-issue
lein ring uberjar

java -jar target\profile-issue-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

Now, when working with multiple profiles the following change to project.clj is important.

```
 ;add key to project.clj
 :target-path "target/%s/"
```

Next attempt

```
lein clean
lein ring uberjar

java -jar target\profile-issue-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class profile_issue.handler.main
```

The reason why it's important to split the target path into subdirectories when working with multiple profiles is explained [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj), around line 250. In a nutshell, when using `:target-path "target/` you'll end up in troubles because different profiles compile into the same directory and when you start the REPL without a `lein clean`, you don't really know what you get.

And btw, when using `:target-path "target/%s/"` the jar and uberjar don't end up in the same directory which is weird.

Any idea?

Comment: I just ran afoul of this same thing, did you solve it?

Comment: There's an issue for this on github: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1721